# Finding a way to create a WLAN between tablet and phone

Tags: wi-fi, networking, wifi-tethering, usb-tethering

I currently own a nokia N900 and am waiting for the my pre ordered Nexus 7 to arrive. I was wondering because since android does not support p2p adhoc networking, as far as i know. Is there any way to create a private lan wirelessly over bluetooth? Maybe setup the tablet or phone as a wireless router?

Also, I am also considering modding a usb cable to be able to plug into the tablet and phone, because from what i heard the tablet also supports host mode, and linux supports IP over USB.

I just need an SSH connection between the two so nothing special as regards protocol usage.

Thanks, and I hope i got my question across clearly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Android, starting from 4.0, does officially support a form of p2p wifi networking called Wifi Direct. A Wifi Direct-capable device can create an access point which any other Wifi-capable device can access. I don't know about Nexus 7 specifically, but Galaxy Nexus does support Wifi Direct so I'd presume that so is Nexus 7.